# detectar char repetido em string c++

Tags: c++, string, char

Olá, Estou tentando fazer um código para detectar a ocorrência de parenteses

```
Na(CO5(Pt
```

Vamos supor algo do tipo, eu teria que detectar a posição dos dois parenteses que estão na string.

tentei usar string.find mas ele sempre me reportar o primeiro parenteses, alguém conhece algum outro método?

aqui o que estou tentando.

```
for (i = 0; i < size(chemform); i++) {
        if (chemform.find("(") != std::string::npos) {

            loc = chemform.find("(", 0);
            start.push_back(loc);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para achar o '(' e sua posição, percorra toda a string, pega cada caractere comparando com == '(', caso verdadeiro, a posição é  igual a variável de incrementação do laço.

codigo:

```
for(int i =0; i<strlen(suastring); i++){
    if(suastring[i] == '('){
         int posicao = i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Se quiser encontrar o parentesis com o `find` de `string` é perfeitamente possível, e parecido ao que estava a fazer:

```
std::string texto ("Na(CO5(Pt");
std::size_t posicao = texto.find("(");

if (posicao!=std::string::npos){
    std::cout << "Parentesis na posição " << posicao << '\n';
}
```

Que vai dar a saida:

```
Parentesis na posição 2
```

O pormenor é que apenas acha o primeiro parentesis e a partir da posição `0`. Para achar os outros já precisa de voltar a utilizar `find`, mas utilizando o parametro `pos` para só pesquisar a partir do ultimo elemento encontrado:

```
std::string texto ("Na(CO5(Pt");
std::size_t posicao = texto.find("(");

while (posicao!=std::string::npos){
    std::cout << "Parentesis na posição " << posicao << '\n';
    posicao = texto.find("(",posicao + 1); //pesquisar o proximo a partir deste + 1
}
```

Saida:

```
Parentesis na posição 2
Parentesis na posição 6
```

[Veja este exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/xbJTVg)

Se quer no entanto fazer algo mais generico, como me pareceu no seu exemplo de código, pode devolver todas as posições do parentesis por meio de uma função, retornando um `vector<int>` por exemplo:

```
std::vector<int> obter_posicoes(std::string texto, std::string elemento){
    std::vector<int> posicoes;
    std::size_t posicao = texto.find(elemento);

    while (posicao!=std::string::npos){
        posicoes.push_back(posicao);
        posicao = texto.find("(",posicao+1);
    }

    return posicoes;
}

int main (){
    std::string texto ("Na(CO5(Pt");
    std::vector<int> posicoes = obter_posicoes(texto, "(");

    for (auto posicao : posicoes){
        std::cout<<posicao<< " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[Este exemplo também no Ideone](https://ideone.com/E7x7Wo)

[Documentação para o `find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/)